# Extracting first digit of int in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a field with number values (111,112,113,211,212,....) and want to extract only the first digit (111 -> 1, 259 -> 2 etc.).

I remember that there was some easy way to do that in field calculator, but not which it was.

Can anyone help?

I don't want to use `CASE WHEN`, since I have roughly 100 various numbers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`left("your field name here",1)` will do the trick.

[`left()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#left) returns a string of a provided length from a field, counted from the left/beginning of the field.

Answer (score 7):

Mathematically will be: `"Field" // 10 ^ floor(log10("Field"))` replace `Field` with the name of your field.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use function regexp_substr:

> Returns the portion of a string which matches a supplied regular
> expression.

```
 regexp_substr( "area", '(\\d{1})')
```

Which means, extract the first single digit